# JSON.stringify prints object to console, object.property prints undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My angular app is giving me a problem where

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($rootScope.user));
```

is printing out the user object like expected, but...

When I try

```
console.log($rootScope.user.objectId)
```

or

```
var id = $rootScope.user.objectId;
console.log(id);
```

I'm getting undefined. What's up with that? userId is definitely one of the properties printed out in the `JSON.stringify`, so... I'm confused.

```
{"username":"thinmint","email":"thinmint@thinmint.com","objectId":"FmjGa7POFH",
 "createdAt":"2015-05-28T18:39:08.362Z","updatedAt":"2015-05-28T18:39:08.362Z"}
```

Thats an example value of `$rootScope.user`.

Comment: can u please show us what u have tried and made the code and whats the purpose of stringify ?. can u please bit clear

Comment: the purpose is to retrieve data from a database. this is what I have tried. I do not know what to try.

Comment: Is objectId a property of $rootScope.user? In your post, you say userId is definitely one of the properties, but your code is referencing objectId, not userId.

Comment: log $rootscope.user once and see if objectId is there.

Comment: Yeah objectId is a property of it. And when I log $rootScope.user, it returns object object like expected

Comment: Time to show us real data. We're all just guessing at this point.

Comment: Please add the contents of your `user` object

Comment: Can you try logging the object itself? Instead of JSON.stringifying it first. Don't know about all browsers but chrome handles this nicely. Then you can check the tree structure of your object. Maybe add that output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var json = {
            "username": "thinmint", "email": "thinmint@thinmint.com", "objectId": "FmjGa7POFH",
            "createdAt": "2015-05-28T18:39:08.362Z", "updatedAt": "2015-05-28T18:39:08.362Z"
        };
        var json1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
        alert(json1.username);
```